# why does UserManager.GetUserAsync not return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

why does UserManager.GetUserAsync not return?

Property IsAdmin will be accessed in blazor UI when i click manually on About page. I don't get why the call to GetUSerAsync does not return. Any clues or mistakes? For simplicity I removed locking code. (doesn't work either without)

About.razor.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Common.Server.Logic.Services;
using Common.Shared.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Common.Server.UI.Pages
{
    public partial class About : ComponentBase
    {
#nullable disable
        [Inject]
        private UserSessionInfo UserSession { get; set;  }

        private string IsAdminText { get; set; }
        private IEnumerable<string> UserRoleNames { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

#nullable restore

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            IsAdminText = UserSession.IsAdmin.Format();
            UserRoleNames = UserSession.UserRoles;
        }
    }
}
```

UserSessionInfo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AspNetCore.ServiceRegistration.Dynamic.Interfaces;
using Common.Server.Logic.Bases;
using Common.Shared;
using Common.Shared.Extensions;
using Common.Shared.Models.Logging.Bases;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Common.Server.Logic.Services
{
    public class UserSessionInfo : LockingBase, IHasUsername, IScopedService
    {
        public DateTime LoginAt { get; set; }

        private UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }
        private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; }

        public IEnumerable<string> UserRoles { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        private string? _username;
        public string? Username
        {
            get
            {
                CheckInitialized();

                return _username;
            }
        }

        private bool _isAdmin;
        public bool IsAdmin
        {
            get
            {
                CheckInitialized();

                return _isAdmin;
            }
        }

        public UserSessionInfo(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            AuthenticationStateProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        }

        private void CheckInitialized()
        {
            if (_username is null)
                // double lock
                SyncLock.Lock(async () => await InitializeAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;

            var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal); // Does not return
            _isAdmin = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, Const.Authorization.Roles.AdminRoleName);

            UserRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var username = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _username, username);
        }
    }
}
```

also (startup.cs):

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();

services.AddScoped<UserSessionInfo>();
```

Comment: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` You can check it first.

Comment: am I using. didn't copy it. addings users and logging in works fine. Just the above code does not. I update my question code with the missing start up code.

Comment: @Henk Holtermann. that is correct, but I use always one IServiceProvider ctor param to keep it clean. this reduces boilerplate signature code when inheriting from base classes. It also makes testing the class a bit easier because you only have to pass one mock instance for IserviceProvider and not multiple params. Anyways, this doesn't solve the descrived problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. (and the reason why it didn't work)

The problem was that I accessed IsAdmin during OnInitialized callback instead of OnInitializedAsync.

Putting access to IsAdmin into OnInitializedAsync everything works!

Answer (score 2):

When an async method doesn't return then `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the first suspect.

Most likely your calling code (the renderer?) is getting your Username and IsAdmin properties overlapped, and then you have a deadlock. But we can't be sure without seeing the whole call chain.

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't need locking or GetResult (or .Wait(), .Result). When you think you do it may be time to back up.